# Get all Radio Button and Text Field values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, input

I have a form on my page that is located in a class .class-lesson.  The form itself only contains text field and radio buttons.  I do not know how many of each are in the form since it is dynamically generated by PHP.  Each new input in the form is named q1, q2, ... qn.

I am trying to get all the values, whether answered or not, and stored into a javascript array.  This is my code so far:

```
// get the value of each input field
var numQuestions = $(".class-lesson label").not(".csubmit").length;

// store each answer
for (var i = 0; i < numQuestions; i++) {
 // store our variables
 var tempAnswer = undefined;
 var tempReference = $(":input[name=q"+(i+1)+"]");
 // loop through each item
 if ( tempReference.attr('type') == 'radio' ) tempAnswer = $(":input[name=q"+(i+1)+"]:checked").val();
 else tempAnswer = tempReference.val();
 // output / store the item
 alert( tempAnswer );
}
```

I am sure there has to be an easier way to do this but I don't know.  This is why I am asking.  If I don't have the :checked then it will just grab the first value of the radio group.

So, how can I make this more efficient?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ ?

Comment: @Meke, your suggestion is good, but you should post it as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: "Look in the API" sounds so rude and isn't much of an answer as much as a slap on the fingers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an entire `<form>` (or any set of inputs) in serialized form, as it would be if submitted to the server normally (without any JavaScript involved), use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), like this:

```
var formData = $(".class-lesson :input").serialize();
//or...
var formData = $("#formID").serialize();
```

If you're submitting via AJAX for example this makes your code incredibly simple, for example:

```
$.post("test.php", $("#formID").serialize(), function(data) {
  alert("Response was: " + data);
});
```